# Err.Raise not giving Err.Description vb.net

Tags: vb.net, error-handling, runtime-error

I have a vb.net program where I am raising an error by `Err.Raise` and then later displaying the error message by `Err.Desription` but it is displaying blank:

```
Public Function CreateSyncDocument()
On Error GoTo CreateSyncDocumentErr
Err.Raise(FNReleaseError.ErrFNPropValueNotValid, , FNPropValueNotValid & "Property Name = " & _
                                l_strIndexName & " Property Value = " & l_objIndexValue.Value)
CreateSyncDocumentErr:
    WriteTraceEntry(Err.Description, False)
End Function
```

All the values inside `Err.Raise` has correct values. I am not sure but I think `Err.Description` should display value of `FNPropValueNotValid` 
Do I am missing any Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility on server

Comment: The `On Error` statement is from the VB6 era and exists solely for backwards compatibility. You shouldn't use it in modern applications. Read up on the [**`Try/Catch` statement**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/try-catch-finally-statement) instead.

Comment: I know but this is not a new application and changing every function is not possible now.

Comment: It is just a typo, the Err.Raise() statement specifies the the help file instead of the description.  Delete that extra comma.

Comment: second parameter is kept blank as its expect source and third is Description

Comment: There are a number of issues with your code. 

First off, I'm forced to ask What is FnReleaseError ?  
Include all the objects used in your code (Like FnReleaseError) what is it?